# How to dynamically add column headers to a tableView which has large number of columns in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, multiple-columns

In my iPhone app, I have a horizontally scrolling tableView. It has 30 columns. The tableView is similar to gridView in ASP.Net.

How can I add the column headers in TableView header's section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` of in the table view delegate.

Comment: thanks for the input. How will this methods be helpful? How to use it to solve my problem? Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: well, if i understood you correctly, then you want to add the header. then you have to implement that methods in your table delegate, returning the height and the view you want to be your table's header. basically, the table view is not designed to have multiple columns, so if you want to scroll horizontally, then you want to add several tables to the UIScrollView, and create the header view for each of them. You can determine what table you dealing with using the parameter tableView: ... that is passed to the delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks Max. Your answer worked. Thanks a lot!! but the only difference is that I did it with one tableView not several tableViews.